Radix DLT User Badge Pattern - How to use it?
I'm following the Radix DLT tutorial about User Badge Pattern here: https://docs.radixdlt.com/docs/user-badge-pattern.
How to practically use it?
Resim
Using resim call-function you don't get the Bucket with the badge in the shell where you run the command. So, you cannot assign (deposit) the badge to "something" (the Account you want to make the OWNER of the Component).
At least, I haven't figured out how to do it.
Manifest
Using the ManifestBuilder method .call_function(package, blueprint, function, args) I initialize the component and get the Bucket with the owner badge (on the worktop).
And now?
I cannot "take" or "deposit" because I don't know the resource address of the badge, so it seems the only option is "try_deposit_batch_or_abort" that requires an account address, but at least does not require the resource address and can be used straightforward.
I still need to find out the way to give it to the Account I want.
I can add a mint_owner_badge function to the component to mint a new owner badges when I want, but that force the component to maintain a ResourceManager in its struct and still cannot be used in the manifest, because I don't have the component address.
Since it needs anyway 2 manifests to be used, I don't think this is the right way to use this pattern.
How this pattern (create an Owner Badge) should practically be used?
